# JEditorPane HTML rendering

Tags: java, html, swing, jeditorpane

I am using a JEditPane to render an HTML text that contains links, and make the links clickable. I have managed to do that but the text and the links are shown in an ugly font and color, the default blue underlined link, etc. Is there a way to change the default behavior of the JEditPane without editing the HTML inside?

Appreciate the help
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding a CSS style, like this:

```
JEditorPane jEditorPane = new JEditorPane();
HTMLEditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit();
StyleSheet styleSheet = kit.getStyleSheet();
styleSheet.addRule("A {color:red}"); //change links to red
jEditorPane.setEditorKit(kit);
```

Comment: Amazing .. thanks a lot... just small question .. now my other text is not wrapped with HTML tags .. how can i change its font also ?